# How to compile or link a .c file included as a header?

Tags: c, sockets, ssl

I am trying to make an SSL socket. I have done some research and I found this answer in stackoverflow too:

[Turn a simple socket into an SSL socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698488/turn-a-simple-socket-into-an-ssl-socket)

I created a C file and I include the same headers:

```
#include <openssl/applink.c>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

But when I try to compile it, it makes this error:

```
socketMng.c:12:10: fatal error: openssl/applink.c: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/applink.c>
```

I can't find that file in `/usr/include/openssl/`. 
I find that file in a folder named mn... I also included using quotation marks instead of <> from that folder but does not work.

Can .c included form the header? (I have never seen it)
How can I solve it?

I already have `libssl-dev` installed.

Thanks

Comment: including C file into another file is legal, but not advisable thing to do. Why do you want to do so ? You need to compile them together instead of including it

Comment: You would only need it on windows if you load openssl dll, if you are not on windows you can remove that include

Comment: @Pras it does not compile without it

Comment: What error do you get if you remove it

Answer (score 1):

> Can .c file be included from the header?

Yes. All that `include` does is to take a file and paste its content instead of the `include` statement. Depending on who you ask it could be bad design, but it is perfectly valid.