# How to convert an existing socket to use TLS/SSL?

Tags: php, ssl, php-socket

It is possible in PHP to initiate a SSL connection, having PHP/OS handle the specific details of the handshake and encryption by using `stream_context` builtin objects, or by using the built-in `CURL` system.

Using the C-like basic older functions, it's also possible to make a regular connection by using `fsockopen`.

Now there's an [answer to this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698488/turn-a-simple-socket-into-an-ssl-socket) supplied for the `C` programming language (although this answer is more complex; it has both a server and a client, while I'm only interested in writing the client bit). This question is: what is the PHP equivalent of doing this?

E.g. I have a regular socket created using `fsockopen` or `stream_context`, how do I change it to a non-regular socket (as obviously; the naïve approach of manually coding ssl is a [bad idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology))?

Some purposes of this include various protocols which had SSL retro-fitted over the old protocol and must be instantiated as regular non-encrypted connections: the handshake happens after various protocol-specific messages (example: SMTP)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the built-in [`stream_socket_enable_crypto`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-enable-crypto) function provides this.