# socket over TLS

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am implementing a socket which accepts connection using TLS.
I found some information on SO on how it can be implemented using OpenSSL. [Turn a simple socket into an SSL socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698488/turn-a-simple-socket-into-an-ssl-socket)

My question is,
Do I have to use openssl (or some other library) to implement TLS compatible socket. Is there any standard C methods to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard C library for TLS. There is OpenSSL which is used a lot and works on many platforms but there are also platform specific libraries like SChannel (Microsoft) or Secure Transport (Apple). And there are many more cross-platform like NSS, GnuTLS, Botan, ... . See [Wikipedia: Comparison of TLS implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations) for more information.

Of course, you could in theory implement everything yourself but TLS is a complex protocol. And implementation of cryptographic stuff are much harder to get fully right than most other programming tasks, so better use an established library.